# Android detect or block floating/overlaying apps

Tags: android

Android enables apps to draw over other apps with android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and it's called a floating/overlaying app. For example Facebook Messenger has always visible chat bubbles at the edges of screen.

My question is: Is it possible to detect or block in Java code any app which draws over my app?

Comment: On newer versions you can ask fro screen recording permission, and compare what you draw and what is on the screen

Comment: filterTouchesWhenObscured on view level set to true would also fix the issue

Comment: I've created a sample to show all ways to detect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71719568/878126

Answer (score 15):

There is a `View#onFilterTouchEventForSecurity()` method you can override to detect if the motion event has the `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED`. This will let you know if something is drawn on top of your view.

```
@Override
public boolean onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(MotionEvent event) {
    if ((event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) == MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED){
        // show error message
        return false;
    }
    return super.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(event);
}
```

If you just want to protect your app from tap jacking due to another app drawing over your app you can add `setFilterTouchesWhenObscured` to your views via XML or programmatically.

Comment: It doesn't work with facebook messenger bubble detection. 
But according to docs - it's the only way.
#Android...

Comment: Here are all ways to detect it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71719568/878126