# On devices lower than Android O, how to programmatically detect whether the bubble or floating notification is turned on?

Tags: android

I searched for some answers, but they are aimed at detecting notification channels above Android O. I did not find a suitable answer on devices below Android O. Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

On devices lower than O - bubbles are not native, so these are not notification channels. These are just custom floating windows of other apps. You can detect them by using `onFilterTouchEventForSecurity` method. This will give you an information that some window is over your view (you can use whole screen view to look for any floating window). You can read about detecting floating windows here: [Android detect or block floating/overlaying apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923301/android-detect-or-block-floating-overlaying-apps)